# Alias in select giving error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

my query is something like this..

```
$query = DB::table('categories')
->select('categories.name','category_company.id as catcompid ','category_company.company_id','category_company.category_id')

->leftJoin('category_company', function($leftJoin){
$leftJoin->on('categories.id', '=', 'category_company.category_id');
})

->groupBy('categories.name')
->get();
```

and my view is like this..

```
 @foreach($top as $tp)  
              <tr>
                  <td>{{ $tp->name }}</td>
                  <td>
                        {{ $tp->catcompid }}

                    </td>
                </tr>
@endforeach
```

it is giving me error like this

```
ErrorException in 7a50b25fc86bfddf956cb4108a130dd2 line 42: Undefined property: stdClass::$catcompid (View: /var/www/test/resources/views/top/index.blade.php)
```

the view is not recognizing catcompid why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems to right, what I suggest you can check 
1) if you have joined on right query.
2) check if you had correctly mentioned

> groupBy('categories.name')

condition.
let me know, if you need further assistance.